# Peer Wire Protocol - Message of length 255 and id 255

Tags: sockets, parsing, protocols, bittorrent, peer-wire-protocol

I am working on an implementation of the BitTorrent peer-wire-protocol. I am blocked by a problem with my implementation. It parses messages correctly until stopped by a message of length 255 and id 255. Below is a dump of the raw data received from the peer. I believe the erroneous message is at offset 0x3ff, with it first parsing len = 0x00FF and id=0xFF.

```
0000000: 1342 6974 546f 7272 656e 7420 7072 6f74  .BitTorrent prot
0000010: 6f63 6f6c 0000 0000 0010 0000 3d76 88ff  ocol........=v..
0000020: 87d6 251a ad81 f5e4 fb90 468b a1a4 5ec0  ..%.......F...^.
0000030: 2d6c 7430 4436 302d 1361 5c7a b4cc 83e1  -lt0D60-.a\z....
0000040: 2d6a a503 0000 0011 0500 0000 0000 0000  -j..............
0000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000220: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000260: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000270: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000290: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000300: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000320: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000330: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000340: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000350: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000360: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000370: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000380: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000390: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000400: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff fff0  ................
0000410: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000420: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000430: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000440: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000450: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000460: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000470: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000480: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000490: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00004f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000500: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000510: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000520: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000530: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000540: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000550: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000560: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000570: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000580: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000590: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00005f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000600: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000610: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000620: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000630: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000640: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000650: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000660: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000670: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000680: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000690: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00006f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000700: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000710: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000720: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000730: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000740: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000750: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000760: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000770: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000780: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000790: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000800: 0a
```

My implementation only handles messages with a length prefix and id, as specified by the BitTorrent protocol, and processes socket data accordingly.

I see nothing in the BitTorrent spec about handling any other kind of message or data when parsing data from a socket. But data of this kind has been received with every peer I try my client, i.e. failing to parse a message with a rediculous length like 0x00FF or 0xFFFF, many more keep-alives than I would expect, and all ending with byte 0x0a. What further does my peer-wire-protocol implementation need?

Comment: is that hexdump from wireshark? if not, is it possible that you're just doing memory operations (reading network buffers) incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

> 0000 0011 0500

This indicates a 17-bytes long bitfield (minus the message type). The large block of zeroes and FFFFs after that doesn't make sense if that's indeed the real bitfield length. So either the length is wrong or the block after that is rubbish.